# Cómo hacer el Deploy de Api en AspNet Core en Heroku desde Github

Tags: asp.net-core, github, docker, heroku, deployment

Estoy intentando deployar en Heroku usando el repositorio de Github.

**Y me está dando el siguiente error en el action:**

Run akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.12.12
Created and wrote to ~/.netrc
›   Warning: Our terms of service have changed:
›   https://dashboard.heroku.com/terms-of-service
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/runner/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Successfully logged into heroku
Added git remote heroku
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "ApiTalleres.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
▸    Error: docker build exited with Error: 1

```
        Unable to push branch because the branch is behind the deployed branch. Using --force to deploy branch. 
        (If you want to avoid this, set dontuseforce to 1 in with: of .github/workflows/action.yml. 
        Specifically, the error was: Error: Command failed: heroku container:push web --app app-talleres-pro
```

The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "ApiTalleres.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
▸    Error: docker build exited with Error: 1

The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "ApiTalleres.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
▸    Error: docker build exited with Error: 1
Error: Error: Command failed: heroku container:push web --app app-talleres-pro
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "ApiTalleres.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
▸    Error: docker build exited with Error: 1

**Mi archivo de dockerfile, en el proyecto es:**
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ApiTalleres.csproj", "ApiTalleres/"]
#RUN dotnet restore "ApiTalleres.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ApiTalleres"
RUN dotnet build "ApiTalleres.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ApiTalleres.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet ApiTalleres.dll

Si falta más info la agrego!

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

te puedes guiar con un wizard , te adjunto mi video como evidencia.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLLLqMQdTdc

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).